# Django Import Error - How do I tell my python where django is installed?

Tags: python, django

So to kick things off, this was all working perfectly until today.

When I ran `python manage.py runserver` today, it spat an error, saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

After a lot of digging, I found that my django is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` (that's where `pip install django` put it), but python was now looking for it in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

How can I tell python that django is installed in that directory above?

FYI, this is my sys.path

```
['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-
scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Comment: Append `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to `sys.path`.

Comment: What happen if you run the python idle on the terminal and type from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

Comment: @amb1s1 It says there's no module called Django

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That would just be a temporary solution that I'd have to run every time. The fix below is better.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? Perhaps one from `brew`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the path to the python path by doing the following in terminal

```
sudo vi ~/.bash_profile
```

Then add this line to the .bash_profile file

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Quit Terminal and open it again. Now you should be good

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I still have no idea why the install directory disappeared from the $PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this.

```
sudo vi ~/.bash_profile
export PYTHONSTARTUP=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

and modify sys.path at runtime with this

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
that could be necessary later for your apache and .wsgi files.
```