# Django test suite claims that PIL is not installed even when it is

Tags: python, django, osx-mavericks

I am working with a team on a Django project. We are running it on Python 3 and have installed Pillow to make use of PIL inside Python3.

One of the Models on our project uses an ImageField.

I am getting an error when running Django's test suite telling me that PIL is not installed, even though it is. But this is only specific to my machine / OS.

Images work fine on the deployed site, and there are no errors. My teammates (all running Windows) can run the test suite fine, and do not get the 'PIL is not installed' error that I get when I try and run the test suite.

What could I be doing wrong that is causing Django not to find the Pillow package when running manage.py test?

Things to note:

- I am running OSX Mavericks (10.9).
- I have fixed python3 errors introduced with Mavericks.
- Pillow and Pillow-PIL (Latest versions) are installed into python3 via the pip3 install command in Terminal.
- I am running Django 1.5.4

This is the specific feedback I get when trying to run 'python3 manage.py test MySite':

> Creating test database for alias 'default'... CommandError: One or
>   more models did not validate: ToolShare.tool: "picture": To use
>   ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imaging Library. Get it at
>   http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I fixed my issue. For anyone that may have the same problem in the future, follow along with this answer, as I did and the test suite ran as expected:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223272/2419492

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then accept it so others know where to look for the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Import Error - How do I tell my python where django is installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222933/django-import-error-how-do-i-tell-my-python-where-django-is-installed)

Comment: @KyleMit I will now. I am new to StackOverflow and wasn't able to respond to my question until 8 hours, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my issue. For anyone that may have the same problem in the future, follow along with this answer, as I did and the test suite ran as expected:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18223272/2419492